# Dynamically importing files in Python

Tags: python

I wish to be able to import a file in Python whose source is a text file that will be often modified.

In other words, let's suppose that I have a file name, `dados.py` whose content in a given moment is:

```
x=[2, 3, 7, 9]
```

(and this is the only line of the file (possible?))

and my main program has the line

```
import dados
```

What I want is that when the import is made I will have an array with the values seen above.

But, if the values of the file dados.py change, the next time that the main program runs it will work with the new values.

The thing is that I don't know if I can have a line of code with variables and if python will recognize that it must execute this line.

The question I am trying to explain in details is because I had a working program with the `x=[2, 3, 7, 9]` writen on the source code. The moment that I replaced that line by:

```
import dados
```

line, python complains with a message like

```
File "testinclude.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to `print(dados.x)`

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is defined within a module, so you must namespace the variable

```
import dados
print(dados.x)
```

Or you can `import x from dados`

Alternative solution would be to use some JSON or other configuration file, then read and load it. It's not clear why you need a Python file only to define variables

Comment: `from dados import x`*

Answer (score 0):

In this instance it is probably better to use a file instead of a python module. However, if you insist on using a module, you can store the data in a variable and access it using the "." operator.